# Python Functions not being called. Only able to print the questions in my print statements

Tags: python

```
history = []
print("Options: 1) Integer Summation, 2) String concatenation, 3) Last Display, 4)Exit...")
def main():

    def summation():
      first_num = int(input("Type the first integer: "))
      second_num = int(input("Type the second integer: "))

      total_0 = first_num + second_num
      print("Sum of two integers is: ",total_0)

      history.append(total_0)

    def string():
      first_num = str(input(":ype the first string: "))
      second_num = str(input("Type the second string: "))

      total_1 = first_num + second_num
      history.append(total_1)
      print("Concatenation of two strings is: ",total_1)

    def last():
      print("The Previous result is: " + str(history()))

    def exits():
      print("Exiting...")

while True:
    x = str(input("Type your option: "))
    if x == "1" or x == "2" or x == "3" or x == "4":
        break
    

    if x == "1":
        summation()

    elif x == "2":
        string()

    elif x == "3":
        last()

    else:
        exits()
    
main()
```

Comment: Why are you using `break` for all the valid options? Also, don't define functions within other functions, specifically, your main function doesn't do anything except define functions

Comment: what should i use instead ? i want the users to only input a number within 1~4 else keep asking the same question. Do you mean i break the loop too early ? currently my code doesnt do anything buy ask me question

Comment: Your while loop works fine. You're ending it early without running anything if you type values 1-4. Also `exits()` doesn't stop the loop

Comment: where should my breaking point be ? very new to coding

Comment: Read the code word for word. You've asked only for an input of 4 to exit it, which `break` does. Why are you doing the same thing for the other inputs? The following if statements get skipped after breaking

Comment: is it because my loop runs before the main so the loops breaks already b4 the functions r being runned

Comment: so i should give the while loop some indentations then drag the while loop up ? on top of my functions or outside the main

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of your while is wrong. It should be inside of your main function.

Comment: Also eliminate the break

Comment: Or all the other functions shouldn't be intended and main should be removed entirely

Comment: @OneCricketeer it would feel more pythonic that way, but I tried to maintain op's logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the main function and just let your script run the while loop.

Also break only during the input that you want to exit the loop. If nothing is after the loop, it exits the script; with your current logic, the while loop exits for every option, nothing is printed beyond your first line and your input prompt, then the main function gets ran, but nothing runs because the main function is actually empty (only defines other functions)

```
history = [] 

def summation():
  global history 
  first_num = int(input("Type the first integer: "))
  second_num = int(input("Type the second integer: "))

  total_0 = first_num + second_num
  print("Sum of two integers is: ",total_0)

  history.append(total_0)

def string():
  global history
  first_num = str(input("Type the first string: "))
  second_num = str(input("Type the second string: "))

  total_1 = first_num + second_num
  history.append(total_1)
  print("Concatenation of two strings is: ",total_1)

def last():
  global history 
  print("The Previous result is: " + str(history))

def exits():
  print("Exiting...")

while True:
    print("Options: 1) Integer Summation, 2) String concatenation, 3) Last Display, 4)Exit...")
    x = str(input("Type your option: "))
    if x == "4":
        exits() 
        break
    elif x == "1":
        summation()
    elif x == "2":
        string()
    elif x == "3":
        last()
```

Note: input() always returns a str type, so there's no reason to cast it